# Como recorro toda una vista en php en busca de coincidencias?

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un motor de plantillas super simple y tengo que ver que coincidencias hay en la vista para sustituirlas, en la clase template tengo en una varible el contenido de la vista:

```
$this->view = file_get_contents(View.php);
$array = array();
```

y para guardar sus coincidencias uso el metodo getview():

```
public static function getview() {
       preg_match('~{{(.*?)}}~'), $this->view, $this->array)
       return $this->array[1];
}
```

al retornar el array me imprime message como es debido, ya que en la vista tengo {{message}}, pero teniendo mas, como hago para guardar las otras?

```
View.php

<p>{{message}}</p>
<p>{{saludo}}</p>
```

hay alguna manera de recorrer la vista obtenida e ir guardando cada coincidencia?

pense un un foreach, pero no funciona

Comment: ¿Desde qué contexto llamas a `getview()`? ¿Estás revisando un array de vistas?

Comment: $this->view es una variable que tiene almacenada el contenido de la pagina, es decir, $this->view = file_get_contents("View.php") y en view.php esta: <html> bla bla {{message}} {{saludo}}</html>

Comment: En ese caso quizá te interese usar [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) que te devuelve un array con las coincidencias. Observa el **Ejemplo 2** del Manual de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías modificar tu función así:

```
    $temp = "";

    public static function getview() {
           preg_match('~{{(.*?)}}~'), $this->view, $this->array);
           for($x=0; $x<count($this->array); $x++){
               $temp .= $this->array[$x];
           }
           return $temp;
    }
```

Se trataría de concatenar cada resultado.